# How to add failure message to Google Test EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, googletest

Is there a way in google test to add a message to a mock expectation in case of a failure?

Similar to other expectations or assertions it'd be nice if I could do...

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, foo()).Times(1) << "Mock did not call foo!";
```

However, this isn't supported. Is there a way to add this verbose information or custom information on a mock failure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no a simple way to do it. You can specialize the template class `FunctionMocker` for `R()` like `template<> FunctionMocker<R>`, `R` is the type returned by `foo`.